# JavaScript inner function needs signature

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm not sure what this means ERROR'Function statements require a function name.'?
The objective is to add a function giving the name. I used a the inner function trying to accomplish this as the most effective solution if I get it working without editing the four last lines of code.

```js
function ChangePerson(name){ 
  changeName:  function(){
    if(this.name != name) {
      this.name = name;
      return name;
   }
};

var newPerson = new ChangePerson("John");
assert(newPerson.name == "John", "The name has been set on initialization" );

ninja.changeName("Bob");
assert( newPerson.name == "Bob", "The name was successfully changed." );
```

**Update**

Also, the previous attempts were

```
function ChangePerson(name){ 
  return changeName(){
    if(this.name != name) {
     this.name = name; 
    }
}};
```

this also does not changeName();.

Comment: Your `ChangePerson` thing is a weird mix between a function and an object literal. Did you mean to write a constructor (to be called with `new`)? Then use `this.changeName = function(){…};`. Did you mean to write a factory function that constructs a new object and returns it? Then write `return {changeName: function() {…}};` (or just `return {changeName() {…}};`).

Comment: No, it's an error error.  In that code, "changeName" is a *statement label* preceding the erroneous function declaration.

Comment: @Bergi Those are tries as I agree but what wanted was to use less code meaning wanting the factory function.  I have tried ```return changeName(){ if(this.name != name) {this.name = name; } }};``` and get that my brackets are not correct when they match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for either

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.changeName = function(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  };
}
var ninja = new Person("John");
ninja.changeName("Bob");
```

or

```
function makePerson(name) {
  return {
    name,                  // name: name,
    changeName(newName) {  // changeName: function(newName) {
      this.name = newName;
    },
  };
}
var ninja = makePerson("John");
ninja.changeName("Bob");
```

Comment: I think you are missing the question as it is to add a function to use the functions as they are already being called. I edited the question to explicitly state the lines that are the same.

Comment: @April_Nara I changed the name of the constructor function from `ChangePerson` to `Person` because I thought it would be a better fit (and also distinguish it better from the factory function), but it would work with the old name as well and the four lines from your question would run fine.

Comment: ``` this.changeName = function(name){this.name = name; }; this.changeName( name ); }``` I'm not sure the syntactic reasons I was incorrect if you could place that in the answer. Thank you.